# Publicly Available 'English Opinion Lexicons' Txt

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I'm an undergraduate and i working on a sentiment analysis project on email [data](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4Khak2hwDi1fjBWSGZpZ2kzZlh0NEd3Nk9vS2FnOU1LTnQ1TmdOalFVRGxod200UXo1dE0&usp=sharing). my first task is to do an opinion mining on the data-set. I train the data with two separate 'English opinion lexicon' data (positive and negative of course ). but the results are not much satisfied. I think if i have more related lexicons results may more accurate. My interest on business related lexicon text.

Anyone have any business related text English opinion lexicons available for public download ..?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it will help you or not, but I find [University of Pittsburgh](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/) has a rich lexicon, and most of those are publicly accessible.